# How to display teamcity android lint results xml file generated by build

Tags: teamcity, android-maven-plugin, android-lint

one of my teamcity builds generates an xml file and I am wondering if there is a plugin to display the file generated against the build.

This file happens to be the android lint results of my android application project but I couldn't find an android lint specific plugin to handle the whole process so I am trying to make the same thing on my own by running the mvn android:lint command of the android maven plugin and then access the xml file somehow.

UPDATE: with regards to the android lint stuff, Teamcity has integrated the Intellij inspections that include lint checks (i think) so I think I should be ok with that.

Overall though, and mostly just out of plain curiosity do you reckon there is a way to display generated files against a build, rather than manually accessing the folder where they got generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Build Artifacts](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Artifact) or you can use the [Teamcity Reporting](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results) feature.

Comment: I got maven lint plugin to create html files and then displayed those in a separate tab in the build results page of teamcity according to the instructions provided in the link above.